# how to count values, if they fall under a separate category and within a group

Tags: google-sheets, sum, pivot, transpose, flatten

Columns D:H show my initial info, where two workstreams (Column D) have different issues occur (Column F:H). These issues fall under one of three categories, under Columns A:B. I want the chart to show the count of the category each issues falls under, making sure it's also showing that it's within a certain workstream.

what i was working with so far is below to match issues to the three categories

```
=INDEX(A:B, MATCH(F1, A:A, 0), 2)
```

and below to count the times a value is within the workstream group (A or B).

```
=countif(flatten(filter(F:H,D:D="A")),"one")
```

How can I combine these two?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hs-Srt-qdOR44V_rmvKF-rC5DThRrQrrCfiA_jAvnH0/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

delete J:M range and use in D1:

```
=INDEX({QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(D1:D9&"×"&VLOOKUP(F1:H9, A1:B12, 2, 0)), "×"), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col2 is not null 
 group by Col1 pivot Col2 label Col1'workstream'"); "TOTAL", 
 TRANSPOSE(MMULT(1*QUERY(
 QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(D1:D9&"×"&VLOOKUP(F1:H9, A1:B12, 2, 0)), "×"), 
 "select count(Col2) where Col2 is not null 
  group by Col2 pivot Col1"), "offset 1", ), 
 SEQUENCE(COUNTUNIQUE(D1:D9), 1, 1, 0)))})
```

[image]

### [formula explanation](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZJ4iDIscQZPf8xT2fbeLpuFyGhulJvkU4dtQi4B12u8/edit#gid=0)

Comment: i don't understand much of what's going on here lol can you explain?

Comment: @andie_6655321 see:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZJ4iDIscQZPf8xT2fbeLpuFyGhulJvkU4dtQi4B12u8/edit#gid=0

Comment: yes i got it work, thank you! another quick question, if i just wanted the numerical values within the chart (no totals either), what would the formula look like?

Comment: and in the explanation it says to multiple by 1 to get 0s instead of blank cells, but there are blank cells

Comment: @andie_6655321 try: `=INDEX(QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(D1:D9&"×"&VLOOKUP(F1:H9, A1:B12, 2, 0)), "×"), "select count(Col1) where Col2 is not null 
 group by Col1 pivot Col2"), "offset 1", )*1)`

Comment: WORKS! thank you! where would the *1 go in the original formula to get zeros?

Comment: @andie_6655321 see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIK2m.png